# WinForm validation: How do you tell if the form contains a control that did not pass validation?

Tags: winforms, validation

I have a composite usercontrol that contains a dropdown "Country" control and a checkbox. If the checkbox is selected, I want to display a validation icon with a tooltip msg that informs the user that a country selection is required.

If the user tries to save the changes, I want to check the entire form, including this composite usercontrol, for errors and, if found, cancel the save.

I expected that, in the form, I would be able to call the Me.Validate function and that the function would recursively check for any controls on the form at any level and return a value indicating whether there are errors or not. Instead, the function appears to fire the validation event for all the controls (I guess this is OK) and UNCONDITIONALLY return TRUE.
Calling the Validate method on the composite userControl also behaves the same.

Do I have to write my own recursive function to check or errors on this form?

I included my code in order for people to offer general suggestions, too.

```
Private Sub ComboOutOfCountry_Validating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles ComboOutOfCountry.Validating
    ValidateComboOutOfCountry()
End Sub

Private Sub ValidateComboOutOfCountry()

    If CheckOutOfCountry.Checked AndAlso _
      (ComboOutOfCountry.Value Is Nothing OrElse ComboOutOfCountry.Value = DBCodeConstants.Omited) Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(ComboOutOfCountry, "Country is required when ""Out of Country"" is selected")
    Else
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(ComboOutOfCountry, "")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CheckOutOfCountry_CheckedChanged1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckOutOfCountry.CheckedChanged

    If Not CheckOutOfCountry.Checked Then
        ErrorProvider1.SetError(ComboOutOfCountry, "")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ComboOutOfCountry_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboOutOfCountry.ValueChanged

    ValidateComboOutOfCountry() 'Clear error icon immediately if they selected a country

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily subclass the ErrorProvider to achieve this - see http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/dsmyth/archive/2007/10/12/custom-error-provider.aspx for an example.